# Excel 2010 automation from C++

Tags: c++, excel, automation, cell

Could some please share a working example of C++ code which performs the following operations:

1. connect to running Excel if any, otherwise throws an exception,
2. connect to current worksheet, otherwise throws an exception,
3. read at least one cell from connected worksheet if any.

I hope someone did things like that before and would kindly share the code. I have a strict directions to use C++ only, while Excel should be any 2003/2007/2010. As far as I have 2010 on main machine I would appreciate example for 2010.

Comment: If you're on Windows and using MFC you can use the [COleDispatchDriver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw39e08y(v=vs.80).aspx) class to talk to Excel via OLE Automation.

Answer (score 6):

Google is your friend: [How to automate Excel from C++ without using MFC or #import](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216686/en-us?fr=1) and [Welcome to the Microsoft Excel 2010 XLL Software Development Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687883.aspx) should help you, especially the second link. Other advices: Dig into the documentation and check the available methods.

Comment: Also, see http://www.as-ltd.co.uk/xllplus/default.htm